# insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm not a server guy but I think I have serious problem using my ubuntu server...
When I do something with apt-get, I get similar errors,
Below is one example I got this day installing something.
Can someone help me fix this, please..

```
sudo apt-get install libv8-dev



Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done libv8-dev is already the newest version (3.14.5.8-5ubuntu2). The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:   apache2-data apache2-utils apturl apturl-common cmake-data cups-browsed cups-server-common ethtool gir1.2-gudev-1.0 gir1.2-udisks-2.0   gnome-session-common hplip-data libcupscgi1 libcupsmime1 libgeonames0 libgutenprint2 libhpmud0 libsane-hpaio libsnmp-base libsnmp30   libtimezonemap-data libtimezonemap1 libx86-1 libxatracker2 linux-headers-4.4.0-128 linux-headers-4.4.0-128-generic   linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-128-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-128-generic linux-sound-base ncurses-term   openssh-sftp-server plainbox-secure-policy pm-utils pyotherside python3-guacamole python3-jinja2 python3-padme python3-pexpect   python3-plainbox python3-ptyprocess python3-pyparsing python3-xlsxwriter qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside qmlscene   qtdeclarative5-dev-tools ssh-import-id syslinux syslinux-common syslinux-legacy vbetool xfonts-scalable xinput Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 294 not upgraded. 5 not fully installed or removed. After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y 
Setting up procps (2:3.3.10-4ubuntu2.4) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults insserv:
warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K05umountnfs.sh insserv:
warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K05hwclock.sh insserv:
warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K05umountnfs.sh insserv:
warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K05hwclock.sh insserv:
warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S05mountdevsubfs.sh insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S06hwclock.sh insserv:
warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S13bootmisc.sh insserv:
warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S11mountnfs.sh insserv:
warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S10mountall.sh insserv:
warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S12mountnfs-bootclean.sh insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S02mountkernfs.sh insserv:
warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S09checkroot-bootclean.sh insserv:
warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S11mountall-bootclean.sh insserv:
warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S07checkroot.sh insserv:
warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S08checkfs.sh insserv:
warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S02hostname.sh insserv:
Service mountkernfs has to be enabled to start service procps insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package procps (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of udev:
udev depends on procps;
however:Package procps is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pulseaudio:  pulseaudio depends on udev (>= 143); however:   Package udev is not configured yet.

        dpkg: error processing package pulseaudio (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth depends on pulseaudio (= 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.10); however:   Package pulseaudio is not configured yet.

        dpkg: error processing package pulseaudio-module-bluetooth (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pulseaudio-module-x11:  pulseaudio-module-x11 depends on pulseaudio (= 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.10); however:   Package pulseaudio is not configured yet.
dpkg : No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already                                                                                                                             No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already                                                           
    g: error processing package pulseaudio-module-x11 (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered while processing:  procps  udev  pulseaudio  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth  pulseaudio-module-x11
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```